# Ruby on rails Jquery data method only returning value of 1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

First stackoverflow question ever.  I've found something that has been puzzling me for quite some time right now and i'm not sure why it's doing this.  Basically what i've done is created a ruby on rails Link_to button, and specified the data that I need passed in to Jquery (An image id) the problem is, everytime I try to get that data value all i'm ending up receiving is the value 1!

Let me give you part of my code and hopefully I can be specific enough to get a good response.

Here is part of my Ruby on rails Gallery index page

```
<% @gimages.each do |image| %>
<% if image.present? %>
<%= link_to (image_tag image.image_url(:thumb)), gallery_image_path(image), data:{id:     image.id, remote: true}, class:"gallery" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, the data:{id, image.id, remote: true} is getting passed in.  The page is not linking to gallery_image_path(image), it is performing the jquery that i've coded.

Here is the Jquery

```
$(function(){
var photo = $('.gallery');
photo.on('click', function(event){
var id = $('.gallery').data("id");
console.log(id);
window.alert("hey");    
});
```

});

The function is getting properly passed and window.alert is displayed, unfortunately for some reason the data that i'm getting back is always "1", that is the only thing that is being logged.

I'll provide you with some of my html after inspecting the elements:

```
<a class="gallery" data-id="2" data-remote="true" href="/gallery_images/2"><img       alt="Thumb 1380148 10152070820204305 182164197 n"   src="/uploads/gallery_image/image/2/thumb_1380148_10152070820204305_182164197_n.jpg"></a>
```

As you can see, the data-id seems to be passing in properly (those were the first 2 pictures that I've provided.

Unfortunately the only thing that is coming up when I console.log is the value 1.  I was wondering if anybody could explain this to me and how I could go about fixing this issue.

Thank you so much guys,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You do `$('.gallery').data("id")`, which returns the data value for the key `id` of the *first element in the matched set only*, as is written in [the API](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2). With the selector `$('.gallery')`, you select all photos so you get the first `id` value every time, which is apparently `1` in your case.

Thus, it should properly work when you replace `$('.gallery').data("id")` with `$(this).data("id")`. `$(this)` refers to the `<a class="gallery">` element being clicked on.